# GPUImage hangs when saving a video with a filter

Tags: ios, objective-c, video, filter, gpuimage

I use [BradLarson/GPUImage](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage) and I want apply a filter to a previously recorded video and save it again. However, neither the completionBlock nor the delegate are called. Re-encoding will hang after a certain time and no error will be returned.

I have looked at the example and there is the same problem. In the example I have disabled `[movieWriter startRecording];` and the delegate was executed, but the video with the filter is not saved.

I think there is an error or something similar while running "startRecording" of the "GPUImageMovieWriter". Does anyone have any idea how this problem can be solved?

Here my code:

```
-(void)applyFilterToVideoAtURL:(NSURL*)url withSize:(CGSize)size completion:(void(^)(void))completion {

    movieFile = [[GPUImageMovie alloc] initWithURL:url];
    movieFile.runBenchmark = YES;
    movieFile.playAtActualSpeed = NO;
    filter = [[GPUImagePixellateFilter alloc] init];
    [movieFile addTarget:filter];


    NSString *pathToMovie = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents/filtered_video.m4v"];
    unlink([pathToMovie UTF8String]); 
    NSURL *movieURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:pathToMovie];

    movieWriter = [[GPUImageMovieWriter alloc] initWithMovieURL:movieURL size:size];
    [filter addTarget:movieWriter];

    movieWriter.shouldPassthroughAudio = YES;
    movieFile.audioEncodingTarget = movieWriter;
    [movieFile enableSynchronizedEncodingUsingMovieWriter:movieWriter];

    [movieWriter startRecording];
    [movieFile startProcessing];


    [movieWriter setCompletionBlock:^{
        [filter removeTarget:movieWriter];
        [movieWriter finishRecording];

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

            if(completion) {
                completion();
            }
        });
    }];
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "the video with the filter is not saved."? I've tested the example included in GPUImage and it runs fine.  

Was using `UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum` to check the video processed btw.

Comment: It was not not saved on the path which is defined by "pathToMovie" variable in my code. The generated file with my code has always 0 byte. I do not want it to be saved in the photo album, too.